# Beta function from exact renormalization group equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, renormalization, flow, effective-field-theory

I'm trying to calculate beta functions from exact (or functional) [renormalization group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization_group) equation (I mean Wilson-Polchinski RGE). I've got the equations but I don't know exactly how to use the renormalization conditions (@$\Lambda_R$) and initial value conditions (@$\Lambda_0$[cutoff]) to solve the equations! If anyone know any good article on this with detailed calculation please introduce it to me. No matter what QFT is used in the article; I just want an example.

Comment: Perhaps this would help: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0611146?

Comment: @ Micheal: Thank you, but I have used Polchinski's equation itself, not the legendre transform of it which works with effective action.